# Target dom element of react component without ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I installed a react-component called react-geosuggest in my project. I need to find the `<label>` dom element in the `<Geosuggest>` component and insert an `onClick` handler to `<label>`. Is there a way to target the `<label>` tag without altering the `<Geosuggest>` component's code.

Here's the JSX

```
render() {
return (
<div>
  <Geosuggest
    id = "searchbar"
    label = " "
    placeholder = ""
    initialValue = {this.state.location}
    onChange = {this.onInputChange}
    onSuggestSelect = {this.onSelection}
    onClick = {this.toggleSearch}
    className = {this.state.expand}
    inputClassName = {this.state.expand}
    // Name a calling reference
    ref = 'geosuggest_component'
  />
</div>
);
```

}

Here's the HTML output

```
<div class="geosuggest">
<div class="geosuggest__input-wrapper">
<label for="searchbar"></label>
<input class="geosuggest__input" type="text" id="searchbar">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use vanillajs. In your component, you can access geosuggest_component ref in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // findDOMNode returns an HTMLElement
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.geosuggest_component);
    // Then search the label
    const label = node.querySelector('label');
    // Now, you can do anything you want with label
    label.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'))   
}
```

I use ReactDOM.findDOMNode because in this case, this.refs.geosuggest_component returns a React component. 
The method findDOMNode will give you the HTMLElement you need.

However, a better way to declare a ref is by using a callback:

```
ref={node => this.geosuggest_component = node}
```

Now in componentDidMount:

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.geosuggest_component);
```